# Import environment variables from text file on network using Jenkins

Tags: svn, jenkins

I have a Unix master and a Windows slave.  I have about 10 subversion repositories, where tags are automatically created by a process outside of Jenkins.  These tags from multiple repositories make up one complete dataset for my application.

When these tags are created, a single text file on a cifs share is created that contains the URLs of these tags for the 10 repositories.  The name of the text file and cifs path is static.

I need to suck in the contents of this file so that I can tell my job what tags to use to compile my dataset.  I do have the ability to adjust the syntax of the text file, to be able to tell my job for example:

```
REPOSITORY1=https://svn/repo1/tags/newtag
REPOSITORY2=https://svn/repo2/tags/newtag
```

I know this is possible; I am new to Jenkins, and have primarily a Windows background.

Answer (score 1):

You need [**EnvInject Plugin**](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin). It will take a property-style file (your file fits that), and inject those as environment variables for Jenkins.

There are many places this can be configured:

- Globally for the node
- Globally for the job
- Before SCM checkout
- As a build step

I assume you need them before the SCM checkout, so use the **Set up a clean environment** example from the plugin page. I suggest to keep both checked: "Keep Jenkins environment variables" and "Keep Jenkins build variables". Then just provide a path to your properties file.